# Xcode target dependency on other target's build rule's output

Tags: c++, xcode

I have an Xcode project with in it one 'core' target (a static lib) and 130+ small 'extended' targets (all executables).  These extended targets all have a dependency on the core target.

I also have a single .xml file that needs to be processed into a C++ .h file, and this generated .h file is needed by cpp files in all targets (core and extended).  I also need this generated file to be located next to the .xml file itself for inclusion in Git.

I added a custom build rule to the core target to process the .xml file.  As it's custom script I invoke a custom binary that does the conversion, and in the output files section I list the resulting .h file's path.  When I then change the .xml file, Xcode calls the build rule before compiling the cpp files in the core target.  So far so good.

But (presumably due to Xcode's 'new build system'), Xcode compiles all cpp files in the extended targets in parallel with the core target (sometimes even before them).  This should normally work fine because the extended targets normally only need the resulting .o file from the core target, so if they only wait for core's linking phase to complete before they start linking themselves that should work.  But in my case, all cpp files in the extended targets that get compiled before the core target has had a chance to convert the .xml file will see an outdated generated .h file.  A second compile then fixes all errors resulting from this.

How can I tell Xcode that the generated .h file in the core target's build script is also relevant to the extended targets?

- I duplicated the same build rule to all extended targets (which I really hate because it introduces a lot of clutter to my project file), but that weirdly didn't change Xcode's behavior at all.
- An other alternative would be to uncheck 'Paralellize Build' from the scheme so that Xcode is forced to first fully compile and link core, but I definitely do not want to give up on building all extended targets themselves in parallel.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an "External Build System" project and/or target for your custom script, then define that as a dependency on your core and extended target. That way, Xcode will wait on the custom script target to be finished before building your core/extended targets in parallel.